# How Do I Use The Google Timezone API In C#?

Tags: c#, google-maps

As the title says. I'm an Apprentice C# Developer and I'm essentially trying to create a clock web part for SharePoint.

I've tried several different examples, but either my Google-fu has failed me or I'm doing something terribly wrong here.

So, is there an easy way to call the Google TimeZone API using C# and store the return for use?

EDIT: Here the code I'm currently using that errors out as soon as I run the program.

```
public static DateTime GetLocalDateTime(double latitude, double longitude, DateTime utcDate)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("maps/api/timezone/json", Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
            request.AddParameter("timestamp", utcDate.ToTimestamp());
            request.AddParameter("sensor", "false");
            var response = client.Execute<GoogleTimeZone>(request);

            return utcDate.AddSeconds(response.Data.rawOffset + response.Data.dstOffset);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var myDateTime = GetLocalDateTime(33.8323, -117.8803, DateTime.UtcNow);
            Console.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class GoogleTimeZone
    {
        public double dstOffset { get; set; }
        public double rawOffset { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string timeZoneId { get; set; }
        public string timeZoneName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static double ToTimestamp(this DateTime date)
        {
            DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
            return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this myself and it is easy indeed. In your url to invoke the api, pick JSON as the return type. Then use Newtonsoft.Json or JSON.Net to deserialize your http request response into your GoogleTimeZone object. From there, you can access the properties normally. Below is a snippet of code to invoke the api and convert the JSON using Newtonsoft.Json from nuget.

```
            //var client = new HttpClient();
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //var response = client.GetStringAsync(requestUri).Result;
            //var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString());
```